# Difference between require and remote.require?

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the difference between require and remote.require as below

```
var path = require('path');
const remote =require('remote');
var fsPlus =remote.require('fs-plus');
```

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md `remote.require` isn't native to node.js. What is your environment?

Comment: I did some changes above please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find something for require and remote.require, maybe it is correct:
`require` is use to get Npm packages
and `remote.require` is to access remotely defined packages in packages.json file of **dependencies** part.
for example

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "TestA modern parcel terminal",
  "version": "0.1.47",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "edge-atom-shell": "^5.0.1",
    "finalhandler": "^0.5.0",
   "nconf": "^0.8.4",
    "fs-plus": "^2.9.2",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "py-logging": "^0.8.1",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "server-destroy": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: nice solution will keep track on your answers